# Form fields in a table

Tags: 7, theming

I want to accomplish something very similar to how drupal blocks admin works. I have a series of combos which need to be rendered side by side in a tabular fashion (not using CSS).

I have dumped the $form object of the blocks module and i can't quite figure out how they do it??? Any ideas?

Comment: Look on the blocks admin pages include file, or look at the admin content overview page ... its all in the form functions used by core modules in your site. I'm on my phone or id find some examples I've done.

Comment: I have been poking around...I think I found a solution by re-theming the form I can wrap each field inside tr and td elements. Not sure if thats how blocks does it but it might work